# Should I use the :hover CSS pseudo-class or the hover() jQuery method?

Tags: css, jquery-selectors, pseudo-class

The question is pretty straight forward. Should I use CSS or JQuery when styling elements that are in the hover state (does one have any real advantage over the other)? To me, using JS seems like a hassle since the pseudo-classes are so easy to use. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use CSS wherever possible; it's more efficient.

It also works better with property cascade and with elements created later.

Comment: I thought I missed something about JQuery but I was thinking the same. CSS seems to be a "cleaner" way. Thank you :)!

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends. If you want your website also displayed on mobile devices it is wiser to make a hover class and attach it with jquery because mobile browser handle hover very sketchy and different.